# Jmeter 5.3: Extract run time 'code_challenge' URL parameter value from request URL which is not shown in any response

Tags: jmeter

We have one URL parameter as "code_challenge" which gets generated at run time, this value we need to extract so that from next runs it can be handled. However since this code value is not captured in any previous requests/responses and need to extract at run time, unable to understand how to achieve.

Tried Regular Extractor choosing URL radio button, but it captures the value from recorded script.

Steps followed:

1. Record script using Blazmeter (Browse URL xx.com>Click Login)
2. Redirected to URL(s) in which one of the url has "code_Challenge" parameter with run time value)
   First URL is: **accounts-xx.com/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/.well-known/openid-configuration**> The response doesn't have any parameter values
3. Second URL is:
   **https://accounts-xx.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=zzzz&scope=ituytutut&redirect_uri=xx.com/callBack&code_challenge_method=ooo&**code_challenge=dsfsdlfhl****
4. In above 3rd point url, Code_challenge value is generated at run time when executed steps from browser.
   However If replayed the recorded script which would have already generated code value hence other requests would fail. Due to this, need to get the code value fetched.

The code_challenge is generated from WS02 service.

Jmeter version: 5.3

Please suggest, or should we need to use Selenium webdriver integration.

[image]

Regular expression which would extract the value from recorded script:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As per [Mitigating Authorization Code Interception Attacks](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Mitigating+Authorization+Code+Interception+Attacks) article:

   > code_challenge The client creates and records a secret cryptographically random string (the code_verifier), which is then encoded using URL safe base64 encoding to transform it into the code_challenge.
2. As per [PKCE in WSO2 IS server article](https://medium.com/@inthiraj1994/pkce-in-wso2-is-server-51a7eeed2d19):

   ```
   1.Plain:

   If a code_challenge method is mention as plain or not mention at all it will take this plain value. Then code_challenge will like:

   code_challenge = code_verifier

   2. SHA256:

   To have the code_challenge as SHA256, we should mention this in request otherwise plain value will be assumed.For SHA256 code challenge will be like

   code_challenge = BASE64URL-ENCODE(SHA256(ASCII(code_verifier)))

   Here base64url is same as base64encoding(used so that all machine can identify as same value) but trailing “=” will be removed and “+” & “/” are placed by “-” & “_” to avoid unnecessary length in URL.(otherwise ‘+’ becomes ‘%2B’, ‘/’ becomes ‘%2F’ and ‘=’ becomes ‘%3D in URL)

   As much as possible, it is better to select the code challenge method as SHA256 then the flow will become more secure and hard to guess(if someone try to brute force it)
   ```

So I think you need to add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and calculate/generate the `code_challenge` using the algorithm used by your server in [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), store the value into a JMeter Variable and use it in the request.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri for sharing details, looks like needs to connect with developer to get JSR223 PreProcessor code to generate using algorthm as suggested since not good at scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the field value empty and then its value gets updated once the request is sent. But you won't see the value in the request.
I had a similar issue, it worked in my case.

Comment: Thanks Aditya, however if code value sent empty value then getting "/callBack?error_description=Code+challenge+used+is+not+up+to+RFC+7xx+specifications.&error=invalid_request"

Comment: @la1 what code challenge method is being used in the request?

Comment: @la1 is the response type "fragment"? If yes, then leaving the code challenge value blank should work. Is there any login process before this authorization?

Comment: Internally using WS02 service, code challenge is generating from WS02 service. Stpes: Browse main domain xx.info> click login button> it calls to and generated code value url

Comment: Okay, may be that's why it's not working. There are few sites, which gives such code value, you can try generating from there and make a CSV and use it. This is the last option, if you don't find any solution. All the best!

Comment: Thanks for info, though code_Challenge value been used which was there while recording and co-related other session tokens able to successfully login and perform actions in Jmeter requests. not sure if any security issue if code_challenge is not validated. However without this code dynamic value able to go ahead with my Jmeter script.